# Same array size, but subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

2 arrays (sheet1TempArray and sheet2TempArray) are declared and populated, both are of the same size 102. All arrarys shown in the code below are declared such as `public sheet1TempArray(), sheet2TempArray() as String`.

I want to check if the elements in sheet1TempArray is in sheet2TempArray, therefore i have the follow function.

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

     IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))

End Function
```

And i have another sub which calls this function

```
For c = 1 To Application.CountA(sheet2TempArray)
        If IsInArray(Trim(CStr(sheet2TempArray(c))), sheet1TempArray) = False Then

           tempNotFoundArray(c) = CStr(sheet2TempArray(c))
        End If

    Next c
```

however, it kept on showing this error (sheet2TempArray(c)) = . May i ask is my looping method wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem which i should have realized earlier.

```
For c = 1 To (Application.CountA(sheet2TempArray)-1)
```

Include -1 at the for loop will solve the problem.